# Negative lookahead's behavior

Tags: regex

I have a task for regexp to recognize 'right' codes:

```
010101
0101010
1111111
000000
```

This is example of 'not right' codes:

```
0110
001
11101
01
```

I wrote regexp:

```
^(?:([01])(?!\1))+$|^([01])\2*$
```

It works.. but I don't understand why :) I can't understand this part:

```
(?:([01])(?!\1))+
```

If this `([01])` is '1-st capturing group', then this `(?!\1)` is `not what we get in first capturing in 1-st capturing group`. But why it doesn't recognize this(it's right behavior, but why?):

```
012
```

? I mean, `2` is not `0`, that's what I expect from `(?!\1)`

Comment: The `(?!\1)` looks ahead to see that whatever was in group 1 is _not_ in front of it.

Comment: The `^([01])\2*$` takes whatever it found in group 2 and finds it 0 or more times til EOS.

Comment: It won't match `012` because the `2` is not consumed before EOS. Only `[01]` is consumed. Remember, `(?!\1)` is just a condition. It is satisfied by a million characters, but it doesn't consume anything.

Comment: @sln thank you a lot! you are wonderful!